# Getting "not enough space" error even i have enough space in sd card

Tags: applications, 4.2-jelly-bean

I have a android jellybean phone [model - ETEl-I4] .i cannot install any apps anymore.i have installed lot of apps before.i can see i have enough space in sd card and i have set default write device to SD card.but when i try to installs apps like skype,viber..etc.i'm getting this error.i read some answers but i think i don't have any cashes problem i have enough space in sd card.
please help me how to fix this issue.

error

[image]

I have set default write device to SD card.

[image]

As you can see i have 5GB space and apps i'm trying to install are less than 50mb.

[image]

Comment: You can't place/move apps to SD card from settings, you can do it with apps like link2sd or apps2sd, but your phone has to be rooted

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever been able to download apps directly to your SD card? I believe the reason for this is that you can only install apps onto the internal memory; not any SD cards. I think you can only move apps after you've downloaded them. If someone can confirm that this is the case, see if you have any images or videos that you can move to the SD card to allow for more space inside the internal memory? Let me know how you get on :)

p.s. I also think the write disk system only works for pictures and the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you might have abundant storage on your sd card but that does not mean you can install many apps. Some part of the app (i.e. may be data or other stuff) are only transfered to sd card. The core part is to remain in internal. Hence, this might be causing problems in your app installs.
Try clearing out some of your internal storage.

Hope this helped.Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Many apps has their own cache. Try to clear cache data in the application manager for each application, which collects a huge cache data.
Note: applications are cached after installing, so required size may be greater minimum of 2 times.